# .toggleClass() a más de un elemento con el mismo id - jquery

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

Genero de forma automática elementos que contienen la misma `id` en este caso con cartas de Bootstrap.

El asunto es que al hacerle `click` la clase que deseo implementar en el primer objeto funciona pero en el segundo no,

¿Alguien conoce como aplicar `.toggleClass()` a mas de un elemento con la misma `id`?

Aquí mi código:

```
                  $("#card_kmx").click(function()
                  {
                    $(this).toggleClass("carta_select")
                  });

                  $("#card_kmx").click(contacto_kmx_cct);

                  ////////////////////////////////////////////////// aqui termina el ready

                function contacto_kmx_cct()
               {

                   if($(this).hasClass("carta_select") == true)
                   {
                      $("#libreta_cnt_odc_libreta_Cc").append("<span id=\"contacto\">hola</span>")
                   }
              }
              /////////////////////////////////////////////////// aquí agrego según clase un objeto en otro elemento
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

El error se debe a que estas usando `$(this).toggleClass`.
La variable `this` hace referencia a exactamente un solo elemento, el *"click-eado"*.

### Solución:

Reemplazar `this` por el `selector` para modificar todos los elementos.

#### Ejemplo:

```
$("#card_kmx").click(function() {
  $("#card_kmx").toggleClass("carta_select")
});
```

---

#### Observación:

No deberias tener mas de un elemento con el mismo `ID`, ya que se supone que debería ser único. Considera usar clases u otro atributo para agrupar elementos.

Comment: Gracias! me ayudo.